# Python: indexing - Project Euler 8

Tags: python, python-2.x

When trying to answer this question using python, I ran into a problem with the indexing on the list I created. The question is:

## What is the greatest product of thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number?

Here is my program:

```
# solves problem 8 hopefully
def problem8():
    MAX = 0
    maybeMAX =0
    n = 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969835203127745063262395783180169848018694788518438858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
    lst = [] 
    while n != 0: ## This loop creates a list from the above number
        n,d =divmod(n,10)
        lst.append(d) #puts each value of the number onto the list as an integer
    lst.reverse()
    while (len(lst)> 12):
        i = lst[0]
        product = (lst[i]*lst[i+1]*lst[i+2]*lst[i+3]*lst[i+4]*lst[i+5]*lst[i+6]*lst[i+7]*lst[i+8]*lst[i+9]*lst[i+10]*lst[i+11]*lst[i+12])   
        maybeMAX = product
        if maybeMAX > MAX :
            MAX =maybeMAX
        lst.remove(lst[0])
    return MAX 
 sol8 = problem8()
 print "The greatest product of thirteen adjacent digits is {}".format(sol8)
```

This is the error I received after running the program above:

```
============== RESTART: C:\Python27\04 Project Euler 5,6,7,8.py ==============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\04 Project Euler 5,6,7,8.py", line 94, in <module>
    sol8 = problem8()
  File "C:\Python27\04 Project Euler 5,6,7,8.py", line 77, in problem8
    product = (lst[i]*lst[i+1]*lst[i+2]*lst[i+3]*lst[i+4]*lst[i+5]*lst[i+6]*lst[i+7]*lst[i+8]*lst[i+9]*lst[i+10]*lst[i+11]*lst[i+12])
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

I couldn't find any other questions that answered this indexing problem, so any help with the code will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `len(lst)> 12` does not ensure that `lst[i+12]` is a valid index.

Comment: I don't get how it supposed to work at all. You basically find `lst[lst[0]]*lst[lst[0]+1]*...`, where `lst[0]` is the first digit. There is no sense in it.

Comment: @Wolfram You're right. In that, the above code took the value at the first index of the list named lst, (i=lst[0]) and then multiplied that to one plus the value at that index and then two plus the value at that index and so on. So in this case, it took 7 which was the number stored in the first spot in lst, and then in the product section, used 7 as the index and multiplied the value stored there with the one stored at 8 etc.

Comment: So what I was trying to do was multiply the first 13 terms in the list together, then store that answer as maybeMAX, compare maybeMAX to MAX, and keep the greater of the two. After that I deleted the number stored at index 0 of lst, which basically shifted all the numbers in lst over one to the left, allowing me to go through all possible products of 13 adjacent numbers with lst and find the largest product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with declaring i as equal to lst[0], which made i equal to the value at that index, and thus in the part that calculated product, it wasn't going through the lst and using those values, it was just adding to 7 which was the original value in index 0.

So I changed:

```
while (len(lst)> 12):
    i = lst[0]
```

to:

```
while (len(lst)> 13):
    i = 0
```

and computed the correct answer.